# Django forms: most DRY way to organize create / update forms for inherited models

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have 2 multi-table inherited models like these:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.PointField()
    ...

class BlogPost(Post):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
```

Similarly, form class for BlogPost also inherits from PostForm class:

```
class PostForm(MapModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Post

    def clean(self):
        ...

class BlogPostForm(PostForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
```

I used to handle create / update for both models in 2 non-class-based views. To make things DRY, I decided to give Django's class-based generic views a try. But due to the lack of examples and user unfriendliness of the related documents and variety of approaches, I am confused.

The idea is to have class based form views for the `Post` model and inherit them for the `BlogPost`. How should I tailor the view classes?

Should I have separate PostCreate and PostUpdate views? Then the two classes are almost identical and not DRY at all.

Should I have a single `FormView` for both update / create of a post? It works for creation but I couldn't figure out how to do this for for update.

Should I build custom view (or two views for create / update) using provided mixin classes instead of inheriting from the views directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right that the class-based view documentation is rather primitive. No doubt it will improve, but for the moment you need to be prepared to experiment and to [read the source](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/generic/edit.py).

You are trying to do two things:

1. Find a good way to organize your views using classes.
2. Refactor your code to avoid repetition.

It's important to tackle these one at a time. Figure out the right class hierarchy first, and only *then* figure out how to factor out the repetition.

Let's have a go. Your class hierarchy is going to look something like this:

```python
from django.views import generic

class PostCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class PostUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class BlogPostCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = BlogPostForm
    model = BlogPost

class BlogPostUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    form_class = BlogPostForm
    model = BlogPost
```

This involves a lot of repetition, but it's clear now how to factor out some of it:

```
from django.views import generic

class PostView(generic.FormView):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class PostCreateView(PostView, generic.CreateView): pass
class PostUpdateView(PostView, generic.UpdateView): pass

class BlogPostView(PostView):
    form_class = BlogPostForm
    model = BlogPost

class BlogPostCreateView(BlogPostView, generic.CreateView): pass
class BlogPostUpdateView(BlogPostView, generic.UpdateView): pass
```

And if you're still unhappy with the amount of repetition here, you can further automate the construction of these classes (using [`type`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type) to create classes at runtime). That's probably a step too far, though, until you're completely comfortable with the use of class-based views.

Comment: How to route to the good view when you don't know if the POST is going to create or update? Is there a good way to do that following this structure?